# Generating function of 1 over binomial

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Is there any known function for which it holds
$$f(x)=\sum_{n\ge m}\frac{x^n}{\binom{n}{m}}?$$

I arrived to this question trying to bound a series and I have no experience with generating functions.

Comment: Well, $\binom{n}{m}=0$ if $n<m$, so you probably want $n\geq m$.

Comment: Very true! Thanks.

Comment: For $m\in\bigg\{0,~\dfrac12,~1\bigg\}~$ we get some very beautiful results. The results for integer $m\in\big[0,~15\big]$ can be found [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QlkpD.png), and those for half-integer $m\in\bigg[-\dfrac12,~\dfrac{15}2\bigg]~$ are available [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1SyjU.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have, if $\left|x\right|<1$
 $$\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{\dbinom{n}{m}}=\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}\frac{m!\left(n-m\right)!x^{n}}{n!}=x^{m}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{m!n!}{\left(m+n\right)!}x^{n}=x^{m}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{m!n!}{\left(m+n\right)!}x^{n}=x^{m}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n!n!}{\left(m+1\right)_{n}}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}=x^{m}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1\right)_{n}\left(1\right)_{n}}{\left(m+1\right)_{n}}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}=x^{m}{}_{2}F_{1}\left(1,1;m+1;x\right)$$
where $\left(m+1\right)_{n}=\left(m+1\right)\cdots\left(m+n\right)$ is the Pochhammer symbol and $_{2}F_{1}\left(a,b;c;x\right)$ is the Hypergeometric function.